# Replace \input{fileX} by the content of fileX automatically

Tags: automation, input

Suppose I have a document with multiple include or input statements

```
\input{fileA}
\input{fileB}
```

etc.

Is there an easy way to generate a single `.tex` file where `\input{fileA}` is replaced by the actual content of `fileA` etc. without copying it manually?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can use the following tools to do this. All of them are on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/) but not all of them are part of either TeXLive or MikTeX, so you may need to manually install them. They need either [Perl](http://www.perl.org/) or a C compiler installed. Both should not be a problem with Linux but might be one under Windows or Mac. However IIRC TeXLive installs its own Perl interpreter.

---

**[`latexpand`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexpand) Perl script:**

> Latexpand is a Perl script that simply replaces `\input` and `\include` commands with the content of the file input/included. The script does not deal with `\includeonly` commands.

#### Installation:

Simply download it from http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexpand/latexpand and run it. You need [Perl](http://www.perl.org/) installed however.

#### Usage:

```
    perl latexpand mainfile.tex > newfile.tex
```

---

**[`flatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flatex)**

> A C program to flatten a LaTeX file into a single file, by explicitly including the files included by `\include` and `\input` commands. Also, if BibTeX is being used, then includes the bbl file into the resulting file. The result is therefore a stand-alone LaTeX file that can be emailed to a collaborator.

#### Installation:

Get the [single C file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/flatex/flatex.c) and compile it, e.g. with `cc flatex.c -o flatex`.

#### Usage:

```
    flatex mainfile.tex > newfile.tex
```

---

**[`flatten`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flatten)**

> A program to flatten a LaTeX root file by copying `\input` and `\include` files into the root file.

#### Installation:

Get [the ZIP file from CTAN](http://mirror.ctan.org/support/flatten.zip), unpack it and run `make` followed by `make install`. You need a C compiler and maybe `flex` for this. However it seems quite old and you might run in trouble because of it. I failed compiling it!

#### Usage:

```
    flatten mainfile.tex newfile.tex
```

Comment: I wanted a Python version of this for my own paper building toolchain so I created one: https://github.com/johnjosephhorton/flatex

Comment: @JohnHorton: Good work! You should consider uploading it to CTAN as well. Just get into contact with the author of the original `flatten`. I don't think he mind having the Python version in the same directory.

Comment: Meanwhile, [`latexpand`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexpand) seems to be part of TexLive (confirmed with v2012) and also of MikTex

Comment: @JohnHorton when I tried to use your script on windows I got some errors. I added couple of lines to your script and gave you a pull request on github.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Unless Apple have done something radical, OS X includes `perl` though it may not include all necessary modules or be the latest version. For most purposes it is usually fine, though. [Caveat: My knowledge is not current but it is hard to imagine they wouldn't still need it.]

Comment: @cfr: I wouldn't know. I never used a Mac, and unless Apple does something radical, I would ever use it ;-)

Comment: @MartinScharrer I guess you meant 'never' ;). I have sympathy for that perspective, though I feel it even more strongly about MS. Hence I'm now using GNU/Linux :). But for current purposes, OS X is essentially just like BSD and the differences between running TeX Live on OS X and on Linux are essentially non-existent. (Case-sensitivity is an exception but this is only a problem if you've created custom packages which turn out to disagree with the migration. Everything else is a straight transfer.)

Comment: @JohnHorton works great on windows 7.  I added:
  Gets \input or \include.
  Adds a new line after replacing with file contents.
 Get new version at https://github.com/dvbrydon/flatex.  I gave you a pull request at github.

Comment: I wonder if any of the scripts take care of the difference between `\input` and `\include`? Otherwise the new file might give different results as the original source

Comment: They all seem to ignore `TEXINPUTS` environment variable for me

Comment: [latexpand](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexpand) does make a difference between \input and \include. It does also take $TEXINPUTS into account in recent enough versions. I tried my best to reproduce exactly the same output, and tested it on several tricky testcases (using pdftotext and diff to check the result). If it does not do so properly, then please submit a bug report (I'm the author).

Comment: latexpand worked for me, including for inserting the bibliography.  flatex on the other hand choked on one of the input files.

Comment: I had some luck with latexpand. However, I am having two issues. 1) The path for my figures are not properly handled. In each sub-tex files (chapters), the of my figures are relative the the path of the sub-tex files. The flattened tex file doesn't handle the path for the figures correctly and keep the path relative to the location of the orignal sub-tex file. 2) have multiple .bib paths. How can I get the bibliography to work properly?

Comment: I don't see latexexpand in the TexLive distribution on OSX.
`find /usr/local/texlive/2020basic -name \*expand\*` doesn't return anything. @Hotschke which OS are you on?

Comment: Responding to myself, it is not in BasicTeX but it is in The Full MacTeX

Answer (score 9):

You need an installed Perl. Save it as `buildFile.pl` and make it executable or run it with `perl buildFile.pl`

```perl
eval '(exit $?0)' && eval 'exec perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}' && eval 'exec perl -S $0 $argv:q'
  if 0;
#use strict;
# 
# Usage:
# buildFile.pl < main-file.tex > main-file.tot
#     
sub p_inc {
  $DateiName = shift;
    if ( open (my $datei, "$DateiName.tex") ) {
      print "%%%---------- open: ", $DateiName, "\n";
      while (<$datei>) {
        if (/^\s*\\include{\s+(\S+)/i) {
          my $include = $1;
          chomp($include);chop($include);
          print "%%%%%%%%% Springe nach ", $include, "\n";
          p_inc($include);
        } else { print unless /^\s*(#|$)/; }
      }
      print "%%%---------- close: ", $DateiName, "\n";
      close $datei;
    } else { print "%%%<===== Datei existiert nicht\n"; }
}
#
@zeilen = (<>);
for $zeile (@zeilen) {
  next if $zeile =~ /^\s*(%)/;
  if ($zeile =~ /^\s*\\include{\s*(\S+)/i) {
    my $include = $1;
    chomp($include);
    chop($include);
    print "%%%%%%%%%%% Springe nach ", $include, "\n";
    p_inc($include);
  } else { print $zeile; }
```

Comment: Can this work for \import as well ? Thanks.

Comment: replace `include` by `import` and it should work. However, `\import` is not a TeX command

Comment: It is from the import package which is useful for including files with relative paths.

Comment: Running on a Mac, I updated Perl at perl.org, but I'm having an error when I run `perl buildFile.pl`: `Missing right curly or square bracket at buildFile.pl line 34, at end of line
syntax error at buildFile.pl line 34, at EOF
Execution of buildFile.pl aborted due to compilation errors.` I don't know Perl, so I am unable to debug. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9):

I developed [FLaP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/FLaP), a python script which replaces `\input`, `\include` and other inclusion directives by the file they refer to while supporting `\includeonly`. In addition it move graphic files around and adjusts graphic inclusion directive (`\includegraphics`, `includesvg` and `\overpic`) accordingly. It supports the `\graphicspath` directive and SVG, EPS and PDF images.

Comment: It seems that this tool also tries to do something clever with `\def`, and this goes easily wrong.

Comment: This is correct, the processing of `\def` is under development, but unfortunately, I have little time to devote to FLaP these days. If you have a specific use case, I invite you to post an issue on the related [GitHub page](https://github.com/fchauvel/flap/issues) and we will look at it.

Comment: Is there a possibility to flatten a preamble that I have in a seperate .sty-file and include that in the main .tex file ?

Answer (score 9):

I've recently discovered [TexSoup](https://github.com/alvinwan/TexSoup), a Python module to parse Latex files inspired by BeatifulSoup. It makes really easy to work with .tex files in a very straightforward way. For instance it allows to target specific Latex commands such as `\input{}` in just few lines of codes.

Suppose you have a `main.tex` file in your folder which reads as follows:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

% ..other commands here..

\section{First part}
\input{file1}

\section{Second part}
\input{file2}

% ..other commands here..

\end{document}
```

If the files `file1.tex` and `file2.tex` are in the same folder just save the script at the bottom in a file named `flatten.py` and execute the command:

```
python flatten.py main.tex expanded.tex
```

to get the expanded file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from TexSoup import TexSoup

def soupify(file):
    """
    Load file in TexSoup object.
    """
    with open(file, 'r') as file_to_read:
        content = file_to_read.read()
    soup = TexSoup(content) 
    return soup

def flatten(soup):
    """
    Expand \input{} commands in a tex file.
    """
    while soup.input:
        soup.input.replace(flatten(soupify(soup.input.args[0]+'.tex')))
    return soup

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    file = sys.argv[1]
    expanded_tex = flatten(soupify(file))

    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        output_file = sys.argv[2]
    else:
        output_file = 'output.tex'

    with open(output_file, 'w') as output:
        output.write(repr(expanded_tex))

    pass
```

Notice: this work for Python 3 only and you have to install TexSoup before (`pip install TexSoup`).  If you have both Python 2 and 3 installed on the same machine you may need to launch the command using `python3` instead of `python` as first word.

Answer (score 6):

I tried all the options mentioned in this post, but the original [flatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flatex) works best for me. There appears to be a [newer version](http://valis.cs.uiuc.edu/~sariel/progs/flatex/), but I was unable to compile it as I am not familiar with multi-file C sources. If anyone could try it and let me know about the outcome that would be great.

The original flatex has an issue as it only creates a .flt (the flattened document), even when you specify a different .tex as the output. But that's not really an issue. I have created a batch file that sorts that out and allows integration with Subversion as well (see this post on my website http://www.jwe.cc/2012/02/workflow-with-subversion-and-latex/).

Answer (score 5):

The question asks for a single TeX file, but the existing answers appear to address the case of `\include` and `\input` statements only. If those statements are generated dynamically by LaTeX commands, then static replacement by a script will miss inclusion of such files.

A solution that captures all files used is:

- add `\RequirePackage{snapshot}` at the top of the document, to use the [`snapshot` package](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/snapshot)
- run [`bundledoc --localonly`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bundledoc) on the resulting `*.dep` file

The resulting archive can then be used with one of the methods described in the other answers (e.g., `latexpand`, `flatex`, `flatten`, or FLaP) in order to generate a single LaTeX file, along the image and other non-LaTeX files included by that file.

(Thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28238/8666).)

Answer (score 4):

I've extended a Python script to handle `\include`, `\input`, and `\import` hierarchically: [master2single.py](https://gist.github.com/tik0/7a8beb82e4e01e91a7ff6146dac06055)

```
USAGE: master2single.py masterfile.tex flattenfile.tex [-v] [-c]
        masterfile.tex      : Input file
        flattenfile.tex     : Flattened file
        -v                  : Verbose mode
        -c                  : Remove all comments
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also [`texdirflatten`](https://github.com/cengique/texdirflatten) which is a perl script.

This worked best for me. YMMV. There is also the consideration that `perl` is not installed by default on Windows machines.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). Not Pandoc's intended usage, but works more or less:

```
pandoc -s file_nested.tex -o file_flat.tex
```

This will convert all \input as well as tables etc to a flat file. When I tried, it did not convert my preamble correctly, so I had to copy paste that part. But all the text in the body of the file got flattened.

Comment: Without the `-s` the ouput is just the text without preamble, but anyway is constructed according to the default template. This can produce unexpected results as change a `\chapter{foo}` to a  `\hypertarget{baz}{\section{baz}\label{baz}}` even if you have not  `hyperref` in the source file, but this can be solved using a custom template.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but here's another python script (let's call it `merge-tex.py`) for the same thing. It could be shorter if there were no diagnostics, but it's not recursive, and doesn't do `\include`.

Use as `python merge_tex.py main.tex merge.tex`.

```python
import sys
import re
from pathlib import Path

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    raise ValueError("Expected two arguments")

in_file = Path(sys.argv[1])
out_file = Path(sys.argv[2])

# https://regex101.com/r/azkAmW/1
regex = re.compile(r"^([^%\\]*)(.*)\\input{(.*)}(.*)$")

with open(out_file, "w") as fout:
    with open(in_file, "r") as fin:
        print(f"Reading: {in_file}")
        for line in fin:
            match = regex.findall(line)
            if not match:
                fout.write(line)
            else:
                # regex groups
                start, comment, input_file, end = match[0]
                if comment:  # nothing to do
                    fout.write(line)
                else:
                    if start:
                        fout.write(start)
                    print(f"Merging: {input_file}.tex")
                    with open(Path(input_file + ".tex"), "r") as finput:
                        [fout.write(inp) for inp in finput]
                    if end:
                        fout.write(end)

print(f"Finished. Merged to: {out_file}")
```