# Preprocess LaTeX file, a latex -E equivalent

Tags: input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace \input{fileX} by the content of fileX automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21838/replace-inputfilex-by-the-content-of-filex-automatically)

I'm developping a framework for managing LaTeX project's dependencies but I can't figure out if there is a simple way of getting a preprocessed LaTeX file.

For instance, if my `main.tex` looks like :

```
\documentclass{article}
...
\newcommand{\specialpath}[0]{../foo/}
\input{\specialpath extracommands}
...
\begin{document}
    \input{introduction}
    ...
\end{document}
```

I want to have:

```
\documentclass{article}
...
% Content of ../foo/extracommands.tex
\usepackage{minted}
\newcommand{\whatever}
% end
...
\begin{document}
    % Content of introduction.tex
    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1-4] % Or even the developpement of the command
    % end
    ...
\end{document}
```

In other words, is there an equivalent of the `gcc` flag `-E` for LaTeX (or an utility capable of doing that)?

Comment: This is going to be difficult on a LaTeX-only level, since `\include{}` will most likely translate directly into a TeX primitive like `\input`. It might be easier to get the raw TeX out, but I'm not even sure if and how that could be done.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370909/preprocess-latex-file-a-latex-e-equivalent?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: I think @Werner is right. Also, if it seems useful, I can easily code a pure (La)TeX program to do that (i.e., no need for a C or perl compiler).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Of course, only TeX can parse TeX. I haven't tested, but I am sure that all those scripts will fail on ``\catcode\`@=1 @input{file}``

Comment: @Maxime: how deep do you want the expansion to go? Once you go real deep, things get very messy. Do you want more than just inlining the `\input` statements? E.g., what about the `\usepackage`, or `\documentclass`?

Comment: @Aditya: I don't think that we can get all occurrences of the \input primitive to be replaced by the file's contents: the problem is that `\input` can be hidden within macro expansions => perhaps we want to expand `\usepackage`... A simpler (but different) possibility is to add the `filecontents` of all files given by `\listfiles` (or by a suitable hack into the TeX primitive `\input`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [\listfiles](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-filesused).