# Creating one .tex file form a structured large document

Tags: external-files, include, document-configuration

I just finished my Ph.D thesis using LaTeX and I create it in a structured way with several folders and .tex documents inside. I have a master main.tex file and add the different chapters, sections etc. with `\include` or `\input` in the master file.

Now I want to create only one `.tex` file with all my thesis. I wonder if there is a what to do that (not cropping or copy/paste) maybe using some package or a script? I appreciate any information.

Comment: Congratulations! Copy pasting is not an option?

Comment: Thanks. Copy pasting is always possible but since it is a very large document with a lot of \inputs and \includes nested, I prefer to find another easiest solution.

Comment: at least some editors (e.g. emacs) provide the means to insert the contents of another file by name into the "working" file; that is what i would do, but only if i was required to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is due to some submission requirement or similar otherwise I would advise against doing this as your current method is much tidier and user friendly (in my opinion). Assuming that you have a large number of .tex your best bet would be to use your preferred programming language to search from string of `\include` or `\input` and then to open that file and insert the text (as one long string) to replace the original command.

If I understand your question correctly then there are several examples in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21838/replace-inputfilex-by-the-content-of-filex-automatically/21840) which you may want to look into.