# Use filecontents everywhere in the document (including after "\end{document}")

Tags: external-files

According to `filecontents`' manual
(version number v1.3, last revised 2011/10/08, p.1) :

> (The comment about filecontents being valid only before \documentclass
>   is, in fact, untrue. filecontents is allowed anywhere in the
>   document’s preamble.)
>
> The filecontents package provides a hacked-up
>   version of the filecontents and filecontents* environments that lifts
>   the two restrictions stated above, namely that existing files are
>   never overwritten and that filecontents must be used before the
>   \documentclass declaration (really, the \begin{document}). filecontents is therefore a more convenient way to write external files from
>   within a LaTeX document than is provided by default by the LaTeX
>   2ε kernel.

However, the following code :

```
\begin{filecontents}{a}
a
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{b}
b
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{c}
c
\end{filecontents}
This is a test.
\end{document}
\begin{filecontents}{d}
d
\end{filecontents}
```

will produce only three files and three warnings:

```
LaTeX Warning: Writing file `./a'.
LaTeX Warning: Writing file `./b'.
LaTeX Warning: Writing file `./c'.
```

Is everything after the `\end{document}` discarded? Is there any way to bypass this limitation? Shouldn't the documentation of `filecontents` be more specific?

Comment: By rule everything after `\end{document}` is discarded, because `\@@end` (the primitive `\end`) command is executed. Nothing to do about it, sorry.

Comment: yes `\end{document}` stops the job and causes the final statistics to be printed and the pdf to be finalised

Comment: While I do not consider myself a TeX expert, if I remember my reading of The TeXbook correctly, the parsing completely stops at \end{document} for a LaTeX file or at \bye for a TeX file.    By the way, \end{document} is just a wrapper for \bye with some very necessary housecleaning at the end of the compile.

Comment: Perhaps the `filecontents` documentation should indeed be revised for this technical note. I have to ask, though: why would you want this?

Comment: @SeanAllred I'm writing a script to "compact" a whole `tex` document into one single file, to ease upload, sharing, storage and deposit on e-print services (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184152/34551). I enclose the `bib` file into a `tex` file thanks to `filecontents`. The trick is that if that `filecontents` is at the beginning on the file, arXiv assume the document is a `bib` file and refuse to compile it. One obvious alternative would have been to concatenate the `bib` file at the end, rather than at the beginning.

Comment: Sounds like [the X–Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/188148) :)

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes, exactly ;-). But I was really curious whereas `\end{document}` was corresponding to a strict "stop reading the source file". And apart from `filecontents`, I never saw any command pretending that they were working anywhere in the source file. So it might be more like "I found a very special case that interest me".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, `\end{document}` causes TeX execution to end by calling `\@@end`, as we can see in `latex.ltx:3900`:

```
\def\enddocument{%
   \let\AtEndDocument\@firstofone
   \@enddocumenthook
   \@checkend{document}%
   \clearpage
   \begingroup
     % 24 lines omitted
   \endgroup
   \deadcycles\z@\@@end}
```

After `\@@end` is seen/expanded/processed, TeX simply stops reading the file.  The final `{filecontents}` has no hope of being seen.

Heiko noted in the comments that you can pull a trick to have TeX simply continue on after `\end{document}`, but beware – hic sunt dracones :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
hello, world

\makeatletter
\let\@@sean@end\@@end
\let\@@end\begingroup
\end{document}
\begin{filecontents}{d}
d
\end{filecontents}
\@@sean@end
```

This creates four files: `./{a,b,c,d}`.

[Heiko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) notes:

> LaTeX does some trickery to get rid of the group for `document` by the environment code. Otherwise, putting the document in a group would raise memory issues, when TeX wants to restore all local assignments after the group. But since `\end{document}` is the end of the TeX job, there is no point restoring assignments afterwards.

I'm still willing to say that attempting to engineer this behavior out of LaTeX is a futile effort or, at the very least, effort better well spent asking why the behavior is needed in the first place.

Comment: `\let\@@end\begingroup` instead of `\let\@@end\relax` fixes the problem. LaTeX does some trickery to get rid of the group for `document` by the environment code. Otherwise, putting the document in a group would raise memory issues, when TeX wants to restore all local assignments after the group. But since `\end{document}` is the end of the TeX job, there is no point restoring assignments afterwards.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks! I probably should have thought of that when TeX was complaining about the extra `\endgroup`, but the memory-management information is very interesting and certainly not something I knew :)