# Consolidated latex code

Tags: input

My latex document consists of hundreds of TeX files that are loaded by the main file using the `\input` command. I need to submit the TeX code to the publisher of a scientific journal for publishing. Is there a way of running the original TeX file, loading all the `\input`'s and produce one TeX file with the code loaded by `\input` in the file?

Comment: when i'm doing this sort of thing, i write a jiffy perl

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See if any of the suggestions in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21838/replace-inputfilex-by-the-content-of-filex-automatically?lq=1 is helpful.