# LaTeX + GIT - mark differences since specific commit

Tags: changes, git

I store LaTeX document in local GIT repository. 
Once I accomplish appropriate part of document I compile it to PDF and send it to my supervisor who is not familiar with LaTeX nor GIT.

However, he ask me to mark all changes which I made since previous PDF by red color.
Currently, I do that manually, so I also need to remove it from my document, once changes are accepted. It is time consuming and source of mistakes.

Is there any automated way to:

- select GIT commit or specific date which will be used to compare against current document version,
- copy current document to temporary file and mark all differences by red font in that temporary file,
- compile temporary file to PDF?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've done this with a combination of `git show` and `latexdiff`. One caveat: this is for single-file documents, might be more complicated if you have split the document into several files and used `\input`/`\include`.

1. Start by getting the version of a file from a previous commit, with

   ```
   git show <commit>:filename.tex > tmp.tex
   ```
2. Run `latexdiff` to generate a new `.tex` file with the differences highlighted:

   ```
   latexdiff tmp.tex filename.tex > tmpdiff.tex
   ```
3. Compile `tmpdiff.tex` as usual.

For `git show` you need to specify the complete path in the repository I think, so if it is placed in a subfolder you need `path/to/filename.tex`.

I wrote a script to automate this somewhat, and also clean up leftovers. Admittedly, I haven't used this much yet, but it may be a starting point.

```bash
#!/bin/bash    
git show $1:file.tex > tmp.tex
latexdiff tmp.tex file.tex > tmpdiff.tex
latexmk -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode tmpdiff.tex
mv -v tmpdiff.pdf Diffed.pdf
rm -v tmp.tex tmpdiff.*
```

Comment: I actually prefer this to my own answer (so +1) but felt that the alternative was worth stating.

Comment: You should use something like `mktemp` instead of assuming the file names "tmp.tex" and "tmpdiff.tex" are unused.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Well, I didn't assume, I *knew* that they were unused *in the case I wrote the script for*, and I did call the script a "starting point". But then I didn't even know about `mktemp`, so thanks for that hint.

Comment: If you have split your document into several tex-files (which I recommend), it's possible to use a tool like [latexpand](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexpand) or [similar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21838/47692) to merge it into one tex-file.

Comment: Why do you need `-interaction=nonstopmode`?

Comment: @stephanmg I think I added it so that I'd always get a PDF, which probably seemed preferrable at the time. Of course, you might get a useless PDF ...

Comment: If you use gitinfo package and a git hook plus the latexdiff thats fun.

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative, here's what I've done in the past.  It's simple but not git-specific (as it happens I was using git at the time though not very well).  It's closer to your manual approach but using an approriate tool to reduce mistakes:

I used the [changes](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/changes) package to mark up the changes *as I make them*.  It needed a little customising to suit my needs (which were similar in that I needed to hand over a highlighted pdf to a non-LaTeX user):

```
\usepackage[authormarkup=none]{changes}
\setaddedmarkup{{\color{blue!75!black}#1}}
\setdeletedmarkup{\protect{\color{blue!25!gray}\sout{#1}}}
\definechangesauthor[name={Chris}]{CH}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\add}[1]{\added[id=CH]{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\del}[1]{\deleted[id=CH]{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rep}[2]{\replaced[id=CH]{#1}{#2}}
\setremarkmarkup{\footnote{#1:\textcolor{blue}{#2}}}
```

The three `\DeclareRobustCommand` lines are merely convenience macros.

This allowed me to use `\listofchanges` as well.

However it didn't pick up the automated (find&replace/regex based) changes I made (`equation~\ref`->`Equation~\ref`, a lot of `acronym` `\ac`s ->`\acl` etc.).  I could have cooked up a regex find/replace to do this but in the circumstances it would have been unnecessary clutter (and made a huge `listofchanges`).

Note that by passing `[final]` either to `\documentclass` or by `\usepackage[final]{changes}` the changes aren't displayed.

A script to insert the `\added`, `\deleted` and `\replaced` macros based on a git diff would no doubt be possible but close to reinventing a bad version of latexdiff so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Just as information, this week a new package [`easyReview`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/easyReview) was uploaded to CTAN. From its documentation seems that it provides commands for replacing, suppressing, highlighting, ... parts of a .tex file. All review changes and comments can be switched off before printing but it doesn't automaticaly apply them.

Comment: @Ignasi that looks quite interesting though I'm not sure it would have worked for me given the dependencies on both `soul` and `todonotes`, both of which I've had trouble with in the past (not insurmountable trouble I'm sure but not worth it at the time).

Comment: This is not what the OP wants, because he already *made* the changes.

Answer (score 6):

`git-latexdiff` was written exactly for this: https://gitlab.com/git-latexdiff/git-latexdiff

I obviously have a strong biais since I'm the main author, but it seems to be the most advanced tool so far.

See also this question: [Using latexdiff with git](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/using-latexdiff-with-git).

Comment: This basically a shell script using `git` and `latexdiff`.

Answer (score 2):

I think `latex-diff` can do this. You may need to update to get this particular feature. Basically, something like [Torbjørn T.'s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266885/77508) is implemented as part of `latex-diff`. There are also some dependencies which are likely not available on Windows.

You'll want to do something like

```
    latexdiff-vc --git --pdf -r rev file.tex
```

where `rev` is the hash of the commit you want to compare with. It should even work with tags

[The manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/support/latexdiff/doc/latexdiff-man.pdf) has details.