# Automatic change tracking and version with git?

Tags: git, revision-control, versions

Is there a integration between LaTeX and git to handle proper documentation versioning?

My goal would be to track changes and revision of a document in git.

And when the document is built the goal would be to highlight changes done since the previous tag/commit automatically.

And eventually to update the tables of changes by using commit logs between current and previous tag/commit.

This idea is in the mindset of quality document currently made with Word that I would like to manage in a better way.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is this what you are currently doing in word? [online Latex diff tool](https://3142.nl/latex-diff/)

Comment: See [package Latexdiff](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff?lang=en) and [possible duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/using-latexdiff-with-git) and [git-latexdiff](https://gitlab.com/git-latexdiff/git-latexdiff). [Related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266879/latex-git-mark-differences-since-specific-commit?rq=1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using latexdiff with git](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/using-latexdiff-with-git)

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late answer. For whatever reason I didn't got the per comment notification. Just the digest a day later. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: God to see you were answered!, now see if the closed duplicate is correct, otherwise future visitors will be confused.