# Exporting LyX file to TeX, with child documents (TeX codes)

Tags: lyx, input, export

I need to export a LyX document to TeX.
The LyX document has child documents (I use `input{}` to refer to some `.tex`-files). These child documents have other child documents themselves (I again use `\input{}`).

I need to find a way to export the LyX file to TeX and get the code of all documents (including the child documents and child documents of the child documents) in **one single** `.tex` file. If I do it in the "usual way", I just get a line with the command `\input{}`, and the reference to the child documents.

Does anybody know a way of doing this?

Please let me know if the question is not clear!
Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2):

When you export a LyX document to TeX, LyX also exports child documents. They are saved to files with the same name but with the extension replaced by `.tex`. The TeX code is there, but in a corresponding "child" tex file.

Comment: Thanks G.M. Your answer makes me realize that my question wasn't clear. The child documents are already `.tex` files. What I need is LyX to export the code altogether (main body + child documents + child documents of the child documents) in **one single** `.tex` file. I hope this is more clear now. I will change the question above. Thanks again!!

Comment: Then see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21838/replace-inputfilex-by-the-content-of-filex-automatically for the next step. If someone who knows about converters in LyX makes an answer showing how to combine the two steps into one, I will suggest to accept that one.