# build index from more \include{file} files

Tags: indexing, include, xindy, makeindex

is there any **easy way** (Iʼm not a programmist) how to build and print Czech-sorted index in document which contains more \include files? I donʼt know how to put here a minimal example. so Iʼm working with this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{czech}

\usepackage[xindy={language=czech, codepage=utf8}, style=altlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeglossaries
\def\xindylangopt{-M lang/czech/utf8-lang}
\makeindex[title=Jmenný rejstřík,options=\xindylangopt]

\begin{document}
\include{lahodova}
%.
%.
%.
\printglossary
\printindex
\end{document}
```

and compiling and building index with this:

```
lualatex sample.tex

makeglossaries sample

lualatex -shell-escape sample.tex
```

without \include files everything works perfectly

here are some lines in Lahodova file:

```
Generační zasazení je dle Mannheima\index{Mannheim, Karl} dáno (stejně jako demografické vytyčení pojmu) především biologickými aspekty.

Literární historik Vlastimil Válek\index{Válek, Vlastimil} memoárovou literaturu označil jako literaturu.

Silvia Nürneberger\index{Nürneberger, Silvia} na příkladu holokaustu uvádí.
```

Comment: Can you please include some more specifications? Give please a sample of lines you included in the 'lahadova' file.

Comment: I added them to my post

Comment: Not a solution to your exact question, but what happens if you use `\input` rather than `include`? I always `\input` rather than `\include` chapters or sections and find it fast enough. It also reduces auxiliary file clutter.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but it doesnʼt work

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that the error is caused by the use of `\input` or `\include`, and does not happen if the content of the included files in inlined? Do you have the `latexpand` script installed? If so, you can use it to inline all the included files. If you do so (`latexpand main.tex > expanded.tex`) and compile the expanded file, does that suppress the error?

Comment: exactly, the problem is caused by the use of \input and \include. 
Iʼm working under Windows, I donʼt know how to run the scripts (there are more of them http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21838/replace-inputfilex-by-the-content-of-filex-automatically )

Comment: Try to minimise the example. Can you reproduce with only one of the glossary and the index? Can you reproduce with only English? What if you compile with a different engine?

Comment: Is the problem occurring with both `glossaries` (`\printglossary`) and `imakeidx` (`\printindex`) or with only one or the other of them?

Comment: It seems you are making confusion between glossary and index. Can you reedit the question focusing only on the topic you are asking? I mean: you load lots of packages and you print also the glossary. You use makeglossaries to sort, but you want an index...

Comment: If i add to the compilation process makeindex after makeglossaries everything works out. If I just run makeglossaries no index is print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example code is based on your code and includes some glossary entries and some index entries:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{czech}

\usepackage[xindy={language=czech, codepage=utf8}, style=altlist]{glossaries}    

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\loadglsentries{defns}

\makeglossaries 

\def\xindylangopt{-M lang/czech/utf8-lang}

\makeindex[title=Jmenný rejstřík,options=\xindylangopt]

\begin{document}

Here’s my \gls{ex} term.
First use: \gls{svm}. Second use: \gls{svm}. \gls{Oxf} is a fence containing \glspl{ox}. Not to be confused with a \Gls{ford} car carrying \glspl{ox}. The \gls{Oxf} fence contains\index{contain, to} also the \gls{OxfU} for \gls{el} cows.

\input{song}

Generační zasazení je dle Mannheima\index{Mannheim, Karl} dáno (stejně jako demografické vytyčení pojmu) především biologickými aspekty.

Literární historik Vlastimil Válek\index{Válek, Vlastimil} memoárovou literaturu označil jako literaturu.

Silvia Nürneberger\index{Nürneberger, Silvia} na příkladu holokaustu uvádí.

\printglossaries 

\printindex

\end{document}
```

where the file `song.tex` is

```
\begin{verse}
Quanto è dolce, o Salvatore\index{Gesù, Cristo Salvatore}\\
di servire a te\\
ed offrire con amore\\
questo \gls{Oxf} a te.

Prendi\index{Prendere, verbo} pure la mia vita\\
io la dono a te.\\
La tua grazia\index{Grazia, increata} mai largita\\
l'hai donata a me.

\end{verse}
```

and the file `defns.tex` contains this:

```
\newacronym{svm}{SVM}{support vector machine}
\newglossaryentry{ex}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{ox}{name={ox},description={a bovin}}
\newglossaryentry{ford}{name={ford},description={a car}}
\newglossaryentry{Oxf}{name={Oxford},description={a city}}
\newglossaryentry{OxfU}{name={Oxford University},description={a place where studying}}
\newglossaryentry{el}{name={élite},description={a restricted group of people}}
```

If you compile with these commands:

```
lualatex sample.tex

makeglossaries sample

texindy -M lang/czech/utf8-lang sample.idx

lualatex sample.tex
```

than you obtain this text:

[image]

followed by the glossary

[image]

and on another page the index

[image]

As you can see the entries in the included files are also present.

Comment: Paolo, thank you very much. your code works perfectly. I finally found out what was the problem: PATH to my files with accents letters: c:\Users\user\Disk Google\práce\sborníky\objetí 2\sazba\