# Is it possible to use 'Find' across \included files?

Tags: indexing, include

I am hoping to write a long(ish) article and was going to use `\include` thus enabling me to work on each section separately. When it comes to indexing I wondered if there was any way to globally search for and find terms to be included in the index or would I need to go through each section in turn. I have tried to do it through the generated PDF - search the PDF and then CMD click the word, it locates it but there seems no way to move to the next occurrence.

Sorry if the question is too basic, I just wanted to make sure before I start.

After more research I suspect the answer is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339409/87808.
I am only a beginner so I will need to figure out how I can adapt this to work for me.
Here is a MWE, but I had to enter all the indexed words by hand I was hoping to be able to find a way to do a global Find (and then replace) to make the index.

```
\documentclass[11pt{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\include{intro}
\include{two}
\include{three}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The three files are, 
intro:

```
\section{Intro}
This chapter will include \index{worms}worms gardens and fleas.
```

two:

```
 \section{Two}
This bit has \index{worms} worms only
```

three:

```
    \section{Three}
Loads more \index{worms} worms here.
```

Comment: If you're asking about a search function in your text editor, you need to say which one you're using.

Comment: Sorry, I use TeXShop.

Comment: (off-topic) in the second section, your use of `\index` with spaces on both sides will result in a too-wide space in that location in the output.