# Is there any possibility to print a single tex file from a multifile project using a LaTeX compiler?

Tags: compiling, conversion, combine, tex-general

I would like to retain the multifile structure of my LaTeX projects, but journals usually require a single .tex file. Is there any way to print such a combined document as a 'cached' file with the help of LaTeX? The solutions provided for this problem ([Submitting a journal article as a single tex file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12554/submitting-a-journal-article-as-a-single-tex-file)) did not seem practical to me.

Here is a trivial MWE:

**sub1.tex:**

```
This is the content of sub1.tex.
```

**sub2.tex:**

```
This is the content of sub2.tex.
```

**main.tex:**

\documentclass{article}

```
\begin{document}

This is a test document.

\input{sub1.tex}

\input{sub2.tex}

\end{document}
```

The combined file would contain the following:

\documentclass{article}

```
\begin{document}

This is a test document.
This is the content of sub1.tex.
This is the content of sub2.tex.

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21838/replace-inputfilex-by-the-content-of-filex-automatically

Comment: Since the output of LaTeX is either DVI, PS or PDF (not .tex), no.

Comment: input just adds the file at that point so it is only a moment's work with a text editor. latex never constructs the whole document in memory so can not help with this sort of task

Answer (score 2):

Using the perl *latexpand* script provided in TeX Live it is possible to get what you want.

Using the same structure as your MWE

```
.
├── main.tex
├── sub1.tex
└── sub2.tex
```

and running from a terminal:

```
latexpand --verbose --keep-comments -o submit.tex main.tex
```

You get the file `submit.tex` which contains:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a test document.

This is the content of sub1.tex.
 
This is the content of sub2.tex.
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. Meanwhile it came to my mind that there may be some other latex files (*.cls, *.sty, *.bst) which could be included in the merged document file. However, performing this actions does not seem to be a trivial task even if one can suppose that the files to be included are in the file subdirectories of a main project directory. I thought of writing a small program which pastes the content of ALL the auxiliary files within `filecontents` before their first use, but each file type requires separate and difficult treatment.

Comment: In that case you should do this "by parts", first you run `latexpand`, then you run `bundledoc`. Although I would simply use `filecontents` in the `submit.tex` file to add `.bst` and extra stuff.

Comment: @TobiR `bundledoc` already does that job  :D

Comment: @TobiR If you dare to write your own _script_ keep in mind the `verbatim` content and commented lines with macros, there things can get a bit complicated (I went through this situation some time ago).

Comment: Thanks Pablo. Do you know a Windows version of `bundledoc`? Which dependencies does this program have? By the way, does the .dep file contain the dependencies in their precedences? Can one rely on this file to write a small code by specifying the standard packages and including the non-standard files without version numbers?

Comment: @TobiR You must have a version of perl (ActiveState or Straberry) installed. The `.dep` file is more or less the same information that `-recorder` gives you, but it is easier to filter (easy is relative). The standard package thing is a trial and error thing, but logic says that any package that you haven't customized yourself is standard.

Comment: Pablo, I realized that we have `bundledoc` on our computer cluster (under Linux), so even our group leader will be able to run it easily (we cannot expect spending too much time with this file conversion from him ;)). Is it sufficient to use `bundledoc` to get a single document from a single project directory (with subdirectories)? Could you please help me with the command to run this script?

Comment: @TobiR Give me a minute to do a test

Comment: OK, thanks, just take your time.

Comment: You will still need two steps, first `latexpand`, then add `RequirePackage{snapshot}` to `submit.tex`, then run `pdflatex submit.tex` and finally `bundledoc --config=texlive-unix.cfg --verbose submit.dep`. You should check the `bundledoc` documentation, I think it is easier to generate a configuration file and then run it.

Comment: Oh, I see. The only problem is that we compile our LaTeX projects under Overleaf, so the LaTeX packages are not up-to-date on our cluster. It would be useful to skip the "pdflatex submit.tex" step somehow which cannot work properly on our computer system.

Comment: @TobiR This step is only for creating the `.dep` file. You should keep in mind that you will run into another problem along the way (I see it in the future), do you have images loaded in separate directories? ... If so, you will have to make other adjustments :) ...more work more fun :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124565/discussion-between-tobir-and-pablo-gonzalez-l).