# Pgfplotstable for journals

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfplotstable, journal-publishing

a) Most journal have old LaTeX distribution or do not want to bother with “complicated” packages such as those derived from `pgf` (see [Using TikZ in journal articles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1952/using-tikz-in-journal-articles)).

I have build a table using `pgfplotstable` and I would like the editors to reproduce its formatting.  However, due to remark a), I suppose it will be better not to include the corresponding code in my submission but something that *self-compile*.
Is there a way to include my table in a fashion similar to externalization with `TikZ`?
Not including another *non-standard* package would be better; the definition of *non-standard* being rather dependent on the targeted journal.

In any case, I suppose the editors would have the table rekeyed to fit their style.  How do you suggest to provide them with the data of the table?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`pgfplotstable` can write the output `latex` code to a file, if you need. Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
 A,B,C
 0,0,T
 1,1,T
 2,2,T
 3,3,T
 4,4,T
 5,5,T
\end{filecontents*}


\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{test.csv}\mytable

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[outfile=mytable.out.tex, % ----->write latex code to the file.
            begin table=\begin{longtable},
            end table=\end{longtable},
            every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule\endhead},
            every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
            columns/A/.style={int detect,column name=A},
            columns/B/.style={int detect,column name=B},
            columns/C/.style={string type,column name=C},
            columns={A,B,C},
            ]\mytable
\end{document}
```

Note the `outfile=mytable.out.tex,` directive in the code. `pgfplotstable` writes the `latex` code to the file `mytable.out.tex` in the *same folder* as your other auxiliary files. The contents of `mytable.out.tex` will be

```
\begin {longtable}{ccc}%
\toprule A&B&C\\\midrule \endhead %
\pgfutilensuremath {0}&\pgfutilensuremath {0}&T\\%
\pgfutilensuremath {1}&\pgfutilensuremath {1}&T\\%
\pgfutilensuremath {2}&\pgfutilensuremath {2}&T\\%
\pgfutilensuremath {3}&\pgfutilensuremath {3}&T\\%
\pgfutilensuremath {4}&\pgfutilensuremath {4}&T\\%
\pgfutilensuremath {5}&\pgfutilensuremath {5}&T\\\bottomrule %
\end {longtable}%
```

When you submit your paper to the journal, replace `\pgfplotstabletypeset[..]{..}\mytable` with the contents of `mytable.out.tex` as usual (you may `\input{mytable.out.tex}`).

For more details, search `outfile` in the pgfplotstable manual. In my copy, it is discussed in detail in page 22.

Comment: As stated in the documentation, some post editing might be required. In addition to replacing `\pgfutilensuremath` by `\ensuremath`, I had to remove `\pgfplotstableresetcolortbloverhangright` and `\pgfplotstableresetcolortbloverhangleft`. I think these are caused by the `dec sep align` option. There are some slight spacing issue when simply removing them.

Comment: In my setup I use `outfile=mytable.out.tex` in combination with `typeset=false` and `\include{mytable.out.tex}`. The option `typeset=false` will only generate the outfile without including the table right in place. So I split all the table generation stuff in to another file and later do the includes in place where needed. Before publishing I exclude the table generation file and do some replacing e.g. `\pgfutilensuremath` by `\ensuremath` and remove the `pgfplotstable` import in the preamble

Answer (score 1):

Stripping out all the pgf commands is the way to go once one has created the outfile.  Also it's worth removing `\usepackage{pgfplotstable}` from the preamble as I've noticed that this can create compilation errors with certain journal style files even if no pgf commands/macros are used in the document.

I replaced the `\pgfplotstableresetcolortbloverhang[left right]` commands with `\ragged[left right]` and it seems to have worked ok.