# Making a table independent of pgf

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, pgfmath, journal-publishing

I use `pgfplotstable` to generate tables to be included in online submission to journals.
I would like to make my paper independant of `pgfplotsable` because compilation of the document is made online with an obsolete LaTeX distribution and clumsy packages handling.

I already asked a question to that effect (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125092/12136)) but I am now facing a more complicated case.
With this, I learned about the `outfile=` option of the `\pgfplotstabletypeset` command which write the tables into a file.

I am using some features of `pgfplotstable` to replace the number in the table by symbols (inspired by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100458/12136)).
Here is an eample similar to my actual code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{symbol column/.style={column type=c,
    postproc cell content/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/@cell content={}{%
        \pgfmathparse{int(less(##1, 0.01))}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        *
        \else
            \pgfmathparse{int(less(##1, .1))}
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            **
            \else
                \pgfmathparse{int(less(##1,1))}
                \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
                ***
                \else
                { }
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
      },
    },
}}





\pgfplotstabletypeset[outfile=output_table.tex,
columns/A/.style={symbol column},
columns/B/.style={symbol column},
]
{%
A B
.001 5
.1 .5
.2  .005
1.7 22
}
\end{document}
```

The output file looks like this:

```
\begin {tabular}{cc}%
A&B\\%
{}{\pgfmathparse {int(less(.001, 0.01))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 * \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(.001, .1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 ** \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(.001,1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 *** \else { } \fi \fi \fi }&{}{\pgfmathparse {int(less(5, 0.01))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 * \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(5, .1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 ** \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(5,1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 *** \else { } \fi \fi \fi }\\%
{}{\pgfmathparse {int(less(.1, 0.01))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 * \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(.1, .1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 ** \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(.1,1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 *** \else { } \fi \fi \fi }&{}{\pgfmathparse {int(less(.5, 0.01))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 * \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(.5, .1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 ** \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(.5,1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 *** \else { } \fi \fi \fi }\\%
{}{\pgfmathparse {int(less(.2, 0.01))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 * \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(.2, .1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 ** \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(.2,1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 *** \else { } \fi \fi \fi }&{}{\pgfmathparse {int(less(.005, 0.01))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 * \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(.005, .1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 ** \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(.005,1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 *** \else { } \fi \fi \fi }\\%
{}{\pgfmathparse {int(less(1.7, 0.01))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 * \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(1.7, .1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 ** \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(1.7,1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 *** \else { } \fi \fi \fi }&{}{\pgfmathparse {int(less(22, 0.01))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 * \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(22, .1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 ** \else \pgfmathparse {int(less(22,1))} \ifnum \pgfmathresult =1 *** \else { } \fi \fi \fi }\\%
\end {tabular}%
```

which depends upon `pgf` for the `\pgfmathparse` and associated commands.

Is there a way to circumvent this without manually editing the table or using external program

Comment: You assign executable code into each cell. However, you could also assign the result of your evaluation into the cell - which would do what you want. Something similar is done in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136331/formatting-an-array-of-complex-numbers-with-pgfplotstable; perhaps you could do the same. The idea would be to assemble your stuff into a macro, and then use `\pgfkeyslet` to copy the content of that macro into the output table (as in the other question).

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger -- Thank you for your input.  Do you have an idea of how to simplify the code I came up with using your suggestion? I posted it in an answer. Feel free to edit or take it over in a new answer and I will delete mine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general it might be hard but here you are only using pgfmath for an inequality test which is a sledgehammer you can avoid:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}



\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{symbol column/.style={column type=c,
    postproc cell content/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/@cell content={}{%
        \ifdim##1pt <0.01pt
        *
        \else
        \ifdim##1pt <0.1pt
            **
            \else
        \ifdim##1pt <1pt
                ***
                \else
                { }
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
      },
    },
}}





\pgfplotstabletypeset[outfile=output_table.tex,
columns/A/.style={symbol column},
columns/B/.style={symbol column},
]
{%
A B
.001 5
.1 .5
.2  .005
1.7 22
}
\end{document}
```

produces

```
\begin {tabular}{cc}%
A&B\\%
{}{\ifdim .001pt <0.01pt * \else \ifdim .001pt <0.1pt ** \else \ifdim .001pt <1pt *** \else
 { } \fi \fi \fi }&{}{\ifdim 5pt <0.01pt * \else \ifdim 5pt <0.1pt ** \else \ifdim 5pt <1pt
 *** \else { } \fi \fi \fi }\\%
{}{\ifdim .1pt <0.01pt * \else \ifdim .1pt <0.1pt ** \else \ifdim .1pt <1pt *** \else { } \
fi \fi \fi }&{}{\ifdim .5pt <0.01pt * \else \ifdim .5pt <0.1pt ** \else \ifdim .5pt <1pt **
* \else { } \fi \fi \fi }\\%
{}{\ifdim .2pt <0.01pt * \else \ifdim .2pt <0.1pt ** \else \ifdim .2pt <1pt *** \else { } \
fi \fi \fi }&{}{\ifdim .005pt <0.01pt * \else \ifdim .005pt <0.1pt ** \else \ifdim .005pt <
1pt *** \else { } \fi \fi \fi }\\%
{}{\ifdim 1.7pt <0.01pt * \else \ifdim 1.7pt <0.1pt ** \else \ifdim 1.7pt <1pt *** \else { 
} \fi \fi \fi }&{}{\ifdim 22pt <0.01pt * \else \ifdim 22pt <0.1pt ** \else \ifdim 22pt <1pt
 *** \else { } \fi \fi \fi }\\%
\end {tabular}%
```

Answer (score 2):

Following Christian's comment, I wrote the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\filtercode}{%
       \pgfmathparse{int(less(\cellvalue, 0.01))}%
       \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1 %
       \edef\cellvalue{x}%
       \else
            \pgfmathparse{int(less(\cellvalue, .1))}%
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1 %
            \edef\cellvalue{xx}%
            \else
                \pgfmathparse{int(less(\cellvalue,1))}%
                \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1 %
                \edef\cellvalue{xxx}%
                \else
               \edef\cellvalue{Z}%
                \fi
            \fi
       \fi
        \toks0=\expandafter{\cellvalue}%
        \edef\value{{}\the\toks0}%
        %\show\value
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\value
}

\pgfplotstableset{%
  create on use/AA/.style={create col/assign/.code={%
      \getthisrow{A}\cellvalue\filtercode}},%
  create on use/BB/.style={create col/assign/.code={%
      \getthisrow{B}\cellvalue\filtercode}},%
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[outfile=output_table.tex,
columns/AA/.style={string type, column type=c},
columns/BB/.style={string type, column type=c},
    % debug,
    columns={AA, BB}
]
{%
A B
.001 5
.0001 .5
.2  .005
1.7 22
}

\end{document}
```

It produce this output

```
\begin {tabular}{cc}%
AA&BB\\%
{}x&{}Z\\%
{}x&{}xxx\\%
{}xxx&{}x\\%
{}Z&{}Z\\%
\end {tabular}%
```

which is what I was looking for.

Comment: Thats a good solution. I do not know what is wrong with the asterisks, but it seems to be working if you write `\edef\value{{}\the\toks0}`. Apparently, they have some special meaning in tabulars (?).

Comment: There is one issue, though: you should termine all lines with `%` to suppress spurious white spaces. TeX is, unfortunately, non-trivally picky about them. As a rule-of-thumb, you should always place `%` after `}` if that is at the end-of-line. But: leave a space after numbers like `\ifnum<xxx>=1 %`. If you keep the spaces, you will observe too much whitespace before your tables.

Comment: If you like to extract a style: write `\pgfplotstableset{create on use/AA/.style={......}}` into your preamble; that should do the job. Any key assignment can be moved into some "shared" place; it'll be active until it is overridden by some other setting.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: I edited the code following your last comment about “extracting a style”.  There is still some copy and paste to do but it is much more streamlined.