# Which journals allow for TikZ in submissions?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1952/using-tikz-in-journal-articles), where most answers point out how to externalise the TikZ parts in some way.

I want to know which journals *actually accept TikZ* in submissions, and possibly which versions.

Comment: Mathematica Applicanda: http://wydawnictwa.ptm.org.pl/index.php/matematyka-stosowana accepts.

Comment: None of the big publishers, Elsevier, IEEE, Wiley, Sage. So you are necessarily left with corner cases.

Comment: This question is somewhat on the edge between TeX.SX and Academia.SX.  It is not really on topic for both.

Comment: @HenriMenke, yes. I was nearly going to post on Academia, but then I noticed the linked question and decided to post here.

Comment: @percusse, in one answer to the linked question it is claimed that some parts of Elsevier allow for TikZ.

Comment: @Turion I don't know any such parts especially in 2010 I highly doubt it.

Comment: I have published papers which used `pgfplots` right from the first submission in Elsevier, Springer and Wiley journals, and no one complained during the publication process.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Because they clip out your images from the PDF submission. I've had long email chains because of these. Mainly because they have to generate HTML versions of the papers and provide the figures.

Comment: For higher revenue publications, Elsevier employ River Valley Associates, who know a lot about latex.