# What publishers who accept LaTeX now accept TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, journal-publishing

Pretty much every place I send articles accepts (really, prefers) LaTeX. So I am asking about publishers who do accept LaTeX.  I have been using Xy-pic a lot.  No problem with publishers.  Will publishers generally be as happy if I send them files with Ti*k*Z?  I'm guessing yes, they will treat Ti*k*Z just as well as Xy-pic.  But I want to check.

Comment: It varies, but you can always make a standalone pdf out of the tikz code; all publishers accept separate copies of included graphs.

Comment: You should ask about this the publisher, and not the internet. If 99% of all publishers accept TikZ, but not the one you chose, then (a) you are in trouble; and (b), the answer you get here is not helpful.

Comment: @Matsmath I often start an MS before choosing a publisher, so general trends are important to me.  And JPi's comment is already very helpful.

Comment: the ams has had quite good experience with tikz (as long as the authors don't make silly mistakes).  tikz is recommended in the ams author handbook and ams is happy to receive submissions using it.

Comment: this question has been flagged for closure as "primarily opinion based".  it could be rephrased as "what publishers who accept latex now accept tikz?", and that should clear (most of) the red flags.

Comment: I'd prefer it to remain open.  There's information in this question.  Besides, why is this primarily opinion based?

Comment: @JPi I guess because the answer would be "it depends on the publisher". At least for the previous version.

Comment: @JPi This is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313045/which-journals-allow-for-tikz-in-submissions

Comment: Even if a publisher accepts TikZ, they may not accept the version you've used. If you use `standalone` files for all images, it will be easier to use exported PDF if necessary, perhaps.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Does ams have good experience with the tkz-euclide package in TikZ?