# Integrating TikZ Graphics in LaTeX for Conference Submission

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello LaTeX Community,

I am currently working on a manuscript intended for submission to a conference (Interspeech 2024) and am facing an issue with integrating graphics. My document relies heavily on the TikZ package for generating high-quality vector graphics directly within LaTeX. However, [the conference's provided LaTeX template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/interspeech-paper-kit/kzcdqdmkqvbr) does not inherently support the TikZ package.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue and found a workaround? Is it generally acceptable to include the TikZ package in a LaTeX document for a conference submission if the template does not support it by default? If not, what alternatives would you suggest to maintain the quality of the graphics while ensuring compatibility with the template?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `does not inherently support the TikZ package`?

Comment: You have to ask the journal, don't you? Related: [publishing - Using TikZ in journal articles - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1952/using-tikz-in-journal-articles)

Comment: Technically, just add the package to its preamble. To make sure, you could contact the conference Organisators. However, I can‘t imagine including common extra packages will cause problems.

Comment: It compiles just fine after adding `tikz` and a tikz picture.

Comment: Also, if a "simple" .tex file si needed, you can externalize the `tikz` pictures and include the generated PDF files.

Comment: there is nothing anyone can say here, technically you can just add `\usepackage{tikz}` and most likely that is fine at their end if they are using  tex. If they require seamless translation to html, tikz might be an issue but in anycase there is no general answer you just haveto ask them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the OP put in the answer there was positive feedback from the conference. Looks like that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I get an answer from the journal:

> You can include the TikZ package. Some packages seem to affect the overall formatting of the paper, though, so make sure that when you include it, nothing else is affected in terms of format.